# Regex Negative Lookahead doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, regex, perl

I'm trying to capture the text between two closest phrases including those phrases, but negative lookahead doesn't seem to work in my situation.

So, this is a part of the text file:

```
<in><il>plural</il> <if>aba*cus*es</if> <il>also</il> <if>aba*ci</if> <sound><wav>abaci001.wav</wav><wav>abaci002.wav</wav></sound> <pr>-ˌsaɪ</pr> <altpr>ˈæbəˌsaɪ</altpr></in>
<in><il>plural</il> <if>fau*nas</if> <il>also</il> <if>fau*nae</if> <sound><wav>fauna002.wav</wav></sound> <pr>ˈfɑ:ˌni:</pr></in>
<il>or</il> <if>fur*ther</if> <sound><wav>far00003.wav</wav></sound> <in><if>far*thest</if> <sound><wav>farthe03.wav</wav></sound>
```

I need to capture every pair of `<if>...</if>` and `<wav>...</wav>` tags.

My regex is: `<if>.*?<\/if>(?:(?!<if>.*?<\/if>).)*?<wav>.*?<\/wav>`

Regex101 Example: https://regex101.com/r/eT4wJ9/1

For some reason, if there're two or more occurrences of `<if>...</if>` tag, this regex matches everything starting from the first occurrence despite the negative lookahead. Why does it happen?

Comment: You shouldn't attempt to process XML using regular expressions. There are several Perl modules on the CPAN that work very well (such as `XML::Twig` or `XML::LibXML`, but *don't* use `XML::Simple `) and make this task very straightforward, as well as providing a tested and much more reliable solution. You will never be certain that a slight variation of the XML data that you haven't thought to test won't break your regex implementation.

Comment: Yes, I know that regex is not the best tool to parse HTML or XML, but this is a one-time task, so I've decided to give it a try.

Comment: I don't understand. Why choose the wrong tool just because it's a one-off task? Do you say, “I'm only going to the nearby shops, so I will take the lawn mower"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a negative lookahead inside the if block also, so that it won't match the nested `if` tags.

```
<if>(?:(?!</?if>).)*<\/if>(?:(?!<if>.*?<\/if>).)*?<wav>(?:(?!</?wav>).)*<\/wav>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eT4wJ9/2)

**Example:**

```
>>> s = '''<in><il>plural</il> <if>aba*cus*es</if> <il>also</il> <if>aba*ci</if> <sound><wav>abaci001.wav</wav><wav>abaci002.wav</wav></sound> <pr>-ˌsaɪ</pr> <altpr>ˈæbəˌsaɪ</altpr></in>
<in><il>plural</il> <if>fau*nas</if> <il>also</il> <if>fau*nae</if> <sound><wav>fauna002.wav</wav></sound> <pr>ˈfɑ:ˌni:</pr></in>
<il>or</il> <if>fur*ther</if> <sound><wav>far00003.wav</wav></sound> <in><if>far*thest</if> <sound><wav>farthe03.wav</wav></sound>'''
>>> for i in re.findall(r'<if>(?:(?!</?if>).)*<\/if>(?:(?!<if>.*?<\/if>).)*?<wav>(?:(?!</?wav>).)*<\/wav>', s):
        print(i)


<if>aba*ci</if> <sound><wav>abaci001.wav</wav>
<if>fau*nae</if> <sound><wav>fauna002.wav</wav>
<if>fur*ther</if> <sound><wav>far00003.wav</wav>
<if>far*thest</if> <sound><wav>farthe03.wav</wav>
```

Comment: `.*?<\/if>` is superfluous

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you, Avinash Raj.